# Makefile : get the command output and use it in a rule

Tags: shell, dynamic, makefile, command, rules

My command get the dependencies of a file passed in parameter and now, I want use it like dependencies into Makefile. I do somethink like :

```
%.dep: %.txt
./mycommand filedepend ${<} > $@

#Tex compilation
$(OUTPUTDIRECTORY)/%.tex.json: %.txt %.dep $(eval $(shell cat %.dep))
    ./mycommand export --to="latex" --path="${<}" $<
    rm $*.dep
```

It doesn't work, the result of the rule should be like :

```
$(OUTPUTDIRECTORY)/%.tex.json: %.txt %.dep foo.txt bar.txt
    ./mycommand export --to="latex" --path="${<}" $<
    rm $*.dep
```

but for independant file (I want one rule for all files)

Comment: You could calculate the list of dependencies before invoking make, put it into an environment variable, and use this variable in your dependency list. BTW, since there are many different *make* available, you should always specify in such a question, which `make` you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate your dependency files in such a way they contain:

```
$(OUTPUTDIRECTORY)/%.tex.json: foo.txt bar.txt
```

instead of only

```
foo.txt bar.txt
```

and then include the dependency files with:

```
-include %.dep
```

The minus is for ignoring the initial include error when the dependency file not yet exists. You can try what happens when you omit it, it shall also work.

Complete example, not tested, maybe i'm missing something, but basically this should work:

```
 -include %.dep
 %.dep: %.txt
    ./mycommand filedepend ${<} > $@   # <-- this must generate the dep file in the correct format


#Tex compilation
$(OUTPUTDIRECTORY)/%.tex.json: %.txt %.dep
    ./mycommand export --to="latex" --path="${<}" $<
    rm $*.dep
```

This is a good source explaining auto dependency generation using gcc, just replace gcc by your custom dependency generator: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/